# Compose-Espresso link to become idle timed out With JetpackCompose LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to test my lazy column in JetpackCompose and I keep getting this error:
[Compose-Espresso link] to become idle timed out

I tried using composeTestRule.waitforIdle() but it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class MainTest {

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    var hiltTestRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 2)
    var composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltTestRule.inject()
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            HomePage(
                context = context,
            viewModel = composeTestRule.activity.viewModels<MarvelViewModel>().value,
            onClick = {}
            )
        }
        composeTestRule.onRoot().printToLog("currentLabelExists")

    }


    @Test
    fun isResultDisplayedOnLazyColumn() {
        composeTestRule.waitForIdle()
        composeTestRule.onNode(hasImeAction(ImeAction.Done)).performTextInput("iron man")
        composeTestRule.onNode(hasImeAction(ImeAction.Done)).performImeAction()

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(TAG_LAZY_COLUMN, useUnmergedTree = true).assertIsDisplayed()
```

Comment: createAndroidComposeRule assumes the Activity sets the composable content for you (usually): https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/test/junit4/package-summary#createAndroidComposeRule() 

also under the hood it creates an activity scenario rule.

Basically it seems you can just use createComposeRule() for your test here and simplify things.

Comment: To expand, I have run into this issue as well and found the conversation here helpful: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160259537

Answer (score 5):

After several hours of trials and experimentation, l found a way to fix this issue in a recent project. I would advise to try the following:

Update compose version to `1.2.0-Alpha06` as Skav mentioned. For me that implies bumping my kotlin version to 1.7.0 which my team is not ready for.

So I did some digging around the `IdlingRegistry` and found that **unregistering** Espresso-Compose Idling resource at the right spot in the test fixed the issue and my UI test passed afterwards.

```kotlin
IdlingRegistry.getInstance().resources.forEach {
   Timber.e("resource ${it.name}    idleNow: ${it.isIdleNow}")
   if (it.name == "Compose-Espresso link") {
       IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(it)
   }
}
```

It is important to note that unregistering Espresso-Compose too early can make your compose ui to fail to display. In my case, l ran this code after the UI is ready before testing for specific UI functionalities.

Comment: I know this is old but on a long shot... could you elaborate on your last paragraph? How do you determine the proper timing to kill the instance?

Comment: @jCrooks, in my case, there was a login flow before landing on the dashboard with compose view present, so l unregistered Idling resource after completing the login flow in my test. Also, l found that you could wait for the compose view to show using composeViewTestRule.waitUntil { ...condition  }. hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is definitely helpful!

Comment: I use 1.5.1 and I still have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I've got this issue too. The root cause was having my composeview GONE. It seems ComposeTestRule IdlingResource don't like then you call setContent on a Gone ComposeView

Comment: So what you can do if you have a "gone" element in the XML. how you can handle this?

Comment: Google seems have fixed that in compose 1.2.0-Alpha06. Give it a try

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73180794/1399483) from @leeCoder, I've discovered that upgrading to **Compose 1.2.0** (**alpha no longer necessary**) fixed my problem **and** there was no need to unregister anything (which was the part that made me the most nervous about his answer).